# How to shrink a VMware virtual disk (vmdk)

Tags: vmware-vmdk

I tried to shrink the size of a VMware virtual disk by doing what I do with AIM/EC2/Xen images: use sdelete -c to clear the empty space on a drive.  However, for VMware, this actually expands the size of the drive.  It went from 2.7 gig to 4 gig.

So then I tried using VMware-vdiskmanager -k to shrink the drive.  It did shrink but to only 3.8 gig.

If you've added then deleted a lot files from a VMware disk, how do you shrink it back down to its smallest size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use VMware Converter 4 to do a V2V while specifying a reduced disk size. Your mileage may vary depending on the type of OS - it's fine for Windows platforms - Linux support is relatively new.

Comment: This works, it's not ideal but it is the easiest suggestion thus far - It's a bit heavy handed and I got it wrong the first time I tried;  ended up stripping out the vmware tools.  Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

One simple, but slow way is to create a new disk, then use a disk cloning tool that works at the filesystem level to copy from the expanded disk to the new disk.  Once you have finished the cloning, then delete the original disk.